# Does anyone have any idea what’s ŋireɽe dialect?

Tags: language-identification

ŋireɽe Dialect or language where it’s spoken and which language group it belongs ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koalib_language

Comment: [What the x is, and belongs to]